# Overwrite default WordPress wording

Tags: filters, language

I'm working on a plugin that changes the password requirements to be a bit stricter, however wherever there is a password field to create a password, WordPress' hints are now no longer accurate (e.g. Password must consists of seven characters).

How can I replace those hints? Is there a filter/function that can help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter `'gettext'`.

Sample code, not tested:

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'wpse_65085_change_error_messages', 10, 3 );

function wpse_65085_change_error_messages( $translated, $text, domain )
{ 
    if ( 'default' !== $domain )
    {
        return $translated;
    }

    switch( $text )
    {
        case 'Hint: The password should be at least seven characters long. To make it stronger, use upper and lower case letters, numbers and symbols like ! " ? $ % ^ &amp; ).':
            return __( 'Use whatever you want', 'your_plugin_text_domain' );

        // more cases here.

        default:
            return $translated;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Had to make some small adjustments, but pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: I noticed today that it didn't change the language on the password reset page. It still contains the old language, presumably because the plugin doesn't get loaded on that page? Do you have any thoughts on how I can change that there as well?

Comment: The plugin _should_ be loaded there too. Not sure without seeing the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
function change_password_hint ( $text ) {
    if(basename($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"])=='wp-login.php' && $text == 'Hint: The password should be at least twelve characters long. To make it stronger, use upper and lower case letters, numbers, and symbols like ! " ? $ % ^ &amp; ).'){
        $text = 'Here is your message.';
    }
    return $text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'change_password_hint' );
```

Comment: Answers should be more than a code snippet. Please improve your answer with an [edit](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/203822/edit) explaining why this would work.